# [move_group-8] process has died [pid 9976, exit code -11

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, move-group, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Im very new to ROS. Im using the "ROS-Autonomous-Quadcopter-Flight"  from trancept. Everything seems to go well until I execute my planned path. I have no idea why the whole thing crashes whenever i execute the path.

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_aerodynamics/C_mxy: 0.074156208
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_aerodynamics/C_mz: 0.050643264
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_aerodynamics/C_wxy: 0.12
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_aerodynamics/C_wz: 0.1
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/CT0s: 1.53819048398e-05
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/CT1s: -0.00025224
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/CT2s: -0.013077
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/J_M: 2.5730480633e-05
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/Psi: 0.00724217982751
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/R_A: 0.201084219222
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/alpha_m: 0.104863758314
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/beta_m: 0.549262344778
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/k_m: -7.01163190977e-05
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/k_t: 0.0153368647144
 * /gazebo/quadrotor_propulsion/l_m: 0.275
 * /ground_truth_to_tf/frame_id: /odom_combined
 * /ground_truth_to_tf/odometry_topic: ground_truth/state
 * /ground_truth_to_tf/tf_prefix: 
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/Quadrotore/projection_evaluator: joints(Base)
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /move_group/capabilities: move_group/MoveGr...
 * /move_group/controller_list: [{'default': True...
 * /move_group/execution_duration_monitoring: False
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/max_range: 6.0
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_con...
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /move_group/octomap_frame: odom_combined
 * /move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::EST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SBL
 * /move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /move_group/sensors: [{'point_subsampl...
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /move_group/trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring: False
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/Base/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/Base/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/Base/max_acceleration: 0.04
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/Base/max_velocity: 0.2
 * /robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 50.0
 * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix: 
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20
 * /rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390/Quadrotore/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    action_controller (action_controller/action_controller)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    ground_truth_to_tf (message_to_tf/message_to_tf)
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390 (rviz/rviz)
    spawn_robot (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [9945]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to dca45a84-fb70-11e6-8178-08002777f95c
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9958]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [9961]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [9965]
process[spawn_robot-4]: started with pid [9969]
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [9970]
process[ground_truth_to_tf-6]: started with pid [9971]
process[action_controller-7]: started with pid [9975]
process[move_group-8]: started with pid [9976]
process[rviz_wenxin_VirtualBox_9932_811209059817823390-9]: started with pid [9977]
[ WARN] [1488037285.166929782]: The 'state_publisher' executable is deprecated. Please use 'robot_state_publisher' instead
[ WARN] [1488037285.178358498]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ INFO] [1488037285.276819666]: Node ready!
[ INFO] [1488037285.374531609]: Loading robot model 'quadrotor'...
[ INFO] [1488037285.534030005]: Loading robot model 'quadrotor'...
[ERROR] [1488037285.535698950]: Group 'Quadrotore' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1488037285.535868403]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'Quadrotore'
[ERROR] [1488037285.536087926]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group Quadrotore.
[ INFO] [1488037285.600704905]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1488037285.609367204]: MoveGroup debug mode is OFF
Starting context monitors...
[ INFO] [1488037285.610395722]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1488037285.620143983]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1488037285.620344055]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1488037285.639503384]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/odom_combined '
[ INFO] [1488037285.653568186]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
spawn_model script started
[ INFO] [1488037285.761778781]: Listening to '/camera/depth/points' using message filter with target frame '/odom_combined '
[ INFO] [1488037285.798708997]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1488037285.891872] [0.000000] Loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1488037285.896629] [0.000000] Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.3
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[ INFO] [1488037285.982902317]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1488037286.089620527]: rviz version 1.11.15
[ INFO] [1488037286.089909653]: compiled against Qt version 4.8.6
[ INFO] [1488037286.090103189]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1488037286.107602342]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1488037286.185497315]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1488037286.187207367]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1488037286.189994828]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1488037286.195399000]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1488037286.202382439]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1488037286.208727238]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1488037286.209085604]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1488037286.209359126]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1488037286.209531392]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1488037286.210562297]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ INFO] [1488037286.233257521]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
Msg Waiting for master
[ INFO] [1488037286.236756088]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
[ WARN] [1488037286.316069890]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: please note that 'action_ns' no longer has a default value.
[ INFO] [1488037286.519513845]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1488037286.519684878]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ INFO] [1488037286.651832300]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Added MultiDofFollowJointTrajectory controller for multi_dof_joint_trajectory_action
[ INFO] [1488037286.652188011]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1488037286.711121136]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.2.15
[INFO] [WallTime: 1488037287.120051] [0.000000] Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1488037287.316338687, 0.001000000]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1488037287.316494554, 0.001000000]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1488037287.316533715, 0.001000000]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1488037288.451072204, 0.001000000]: Camera Plugin (robotNamespace = /), Info: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[INFO] [WallTime: 1488037288.461857] [0.001000] Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned model
[ INFO] [1488037288.484168356, 0.001000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ WARN] [1488037288.484283128, 0.001000000]: dynamic reconfigure is not enabled for this image topic [camera/rgb/image_raw] becuase <cameraName> is not specified
[ INFO] [1488037288.605910453, 0.001000000]: imu plugin missing <xyzOffset>, defaults to 0s
[ INFO] [1488037288.606319524, 0.001000000]: imu plugin missing <rpyOffset>, defaults to 0s
[spawn_robot-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/wenxin/.ros/log/dca45a84-fb70-11e6-8178-08002777f95c/spawn_robot-4*.log
Dbg plugin model name: quadrotor
[ INFO] [1488037289.294931140, 0.001000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1488037289.295273528, 0.001000000]: Callback thread id=7ff2e77fe700
[ INFO] [1488037289.303140142, 0.001000000]: gazebo controller manager plugin is waiting for urdf: //robot_description on the param server.  (make sure there is a rosparam by that name in the ros parameter server, otherwise, this plugin blocks simulation forever).
[ INFO] [1488037289.412763296, 0.001000000]: gazebo controller manager got pr2.xml from param server, parsing it...
[ WARN] [1488037289.417436338, 0.001000000]: No transmissions were specified in the robot description.
[ WARN] [1488037289.417785639, 0.001000000]: None of the joints in the robot desription matches up to a motor. The robot is uncontrollable.
[ WARN] [1488037289.440273725, 0.001000000]: No transmissions were specified in the robot description.
[ WARN] [1488037289.440378551, 0.001000000]: None of the joints in the robot desription matches up to a motor. The robot is uncontrollable.
Warning [gazebo_quadrotor_simple_controller.cpp:57] The GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController plugin is DEPRECATED in ROS hydro. Please use the twist_controller in package hector_quadrotor_controller instead.
[ INFO] [1488037289.489495035, 0.001000000]: Using imu information on topic raw_imu as source of orientation and angular velocity.
[ INFO] [1488037289.514578873, 0.001000000]: Using state information on topic ground_truth/state as source of state information.
[ INFO] [1488037289.563688840, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1488037289.766189150, 0.114000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ INFO] [1488037292.841409808, 1.576000000]: Loading robot model 'quadrotor'...
[ INFO] [1488037293.160375538, 1.681000000]: Loading robot model 'quadrotor'...
[ERROR] [1488037293.168960399, 1.684000000]: Group 'Quadrotore' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1488037293.169177171, 1.684000000]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'Quadrotore'
[ERROR] [1488037293.180515084, 1.686000000]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group Quadrotore.
[ INFO] [1488037294.009477931, 1.961000000]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1488037294.044243482, 1.971000000]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1488037295.059454241, 2.321000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'Quadrotore' in namespace ''
Warning [Publisher.cc:134] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/pose/local/info, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
[ INFO] [1488037297.026845407, 2.811000000]: TrajectoryExecution will use old service capability.
[ INFO] [1488037297.027062759, 2.811000000]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group Quadrotore.
[ INFO] [1488037297.027165275, 2.811000000]: Looking around: no
[ INFO] [1488037297.027273148, 2.811000000]: Replanning: no
Warning [Publisher.cc:134] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/physics/contacts, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
[ INFO] [1488037669.801610217, 118.429000000]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[ INFO] [1488037669.807850329, 118.429000000]: No optimization objective specified, defaulting to PathLengthOptimizationObjective
[ INFO] [1488037669.811840185, 118.430000000]: Planner configuration 'Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]' will use planner 'geometric::PRMstar'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[ INFO] [1488037669.813161382, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1488037669.813927213, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1488037669.814084896, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1488037669.814173208, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1488037669.814228498, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: problem definition is not set, deferring setup completion...
[ INFO] [1488037669.828556168, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1488037669.835439214, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1488037669.839148695, 118.430000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1488037669.854662295, 118.440000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Starting planning with 2 states already in datastructure
[ INFO] [1488037674.819166098, 120.016000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 438 states
[ INFO] [1488037674.834313167, 120.026000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 512 states
[ INFO] [1488037674.835099842, 120.026000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 576 states
[ INFO] [1488037674.835793452, 120.026000000]: Quadrotore[PRMstarkConfigDefault]: Created 615 states
[ INFO] [1488037674.837337106, 120.026000000]: ProblemDefinition: Adding approximate solution from planner PathHybridization
[ INFO] [1488037674.837506468, 120.026000000]: ParallelPlan::solve(): Solution found by one or more threads in 5.023202 seconds
[ INFO] [1488037905.292840872, 189.154000000]: Received new trajectory execution service request...
[move_group-8] process has died [pid 9976, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/wenxin/.ros/log/dca45a84-fb70-11e6-8178-08002777f95c/move_group-8.log].
log file: /home/wenxin/.ros/log/dca45a84-fb70-11e6-8178-08002777f95c/move_group-8*.log
```

sorry for the long post. any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255594/%5Bmove_group-8%5D-process-has-died-%5Bpid-9976,-exit-code--11/) by [Wen Xin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29388/wen-xin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orko](https://answers.ros.org/users/30575/orko/) on 2017-06-01**:
could you solve this issue? I have the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem with you.
it seems that Moveit! can not execute the quadcopter directly. Because this is not a joint type robot.
One way to slove this problem is that, you should write the action and simple_control_management by yourself.
You can refer:
https://www.wilselby.com/research/ros-integration/3d-mapping-navigation/

---

Originally posted by [pyni_sjtu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28882/pyni_sjtu/) with karma: 36 on 2017-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0